# calculus where m is the slope and b is the y intercept

Tags: calculus

An equation to the tangent line of $h(x)=\tan (x)+\cos (x)$ is given by $y=mx+b$, where $m$ is the slope and $b$ is the $y$-intercept. If $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ find $m$

Comment: Try starting by refreshing some notions (at least the definition) about derivate of a function in $\mathbb{R}$. It should be easy then :)

Comment: You have stated the question (find m), but you haven't told us what you have tried. Where do you need help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

$h(x) = \tan x + \cos x, \tag{1}$

then

$h'(x) = \sec^2 x - \sin x = 1  / (\cos^2 x) - \sin x, \tag{2}$

so if $x = \pi / 4$,

$m = h'(\pi / 4)  = 2 -  \sqrt 2 / 2.  \tag{3}$

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***